# single makefile for building multiple cpp files

Tags: makefile

I am trying to create some sample single file c plus plus sample programs. I want to use makefile based build system with single makefile for all sample. Sample.cpp should be built as sample.exe.
I can pass .cpp filename as parameter to makefile. 
I am assuming this group of sample files will use same library dependencies only changing part will be filename.

Answer (score 0):

```
%.exe: %.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $< $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```